# Transformar el tiempo en segundos en una tabla usando pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

Tengo 3 columnas que guardan el tiempo de procesamiento en este formato Min:sec. Quiero transformalo en segundos para poder trabajar luego con ellos.

(Probablemente si el tiempo transcurrido se demorara horas supongo que el formato definitivo sería horas:minutos:segundos)

Pongo mi tabla y el resultado que me gustaría obtener.

Mi tabla

```
 Compression_level Size (M) Real time (s) User time (s) Sys time (s)
0                  0      265      0:19.938      0:24.649      0:3.062
1                  1       76      0:17.910      0:25.929      0:3.098
2                  2       74      1:02.619      0:27.724      0:3.014
3                  3       73      0:20.607      0:27.937      0:3.193
4                  4       67      0:19.598      0:28.853      0:2.925
5                  5       67      0:21.032      0:30.119      0:3.206
6                  6       66      0:27.013      0:31.462      0:3.106
7                  7       65      0:27.337      0:36.226      0:3.060
8                  8       64      0:37.651      0:47.246      0:2.933
9                  9       64      0:59.241       1:8.333      0:3.027
```

Y como me gustaria que quedara

```
df["Real time (s)"]
0    19.938
1    17.910
2    62.619
...
```

He encontrado este código que funciona tras recibir un valor pero no sé como itenerarlo en la tabla

```
x = time.strptime("00:01:00","%H:%M:%S")
datetime.timedelta(hours=x.tm_hour,minutes=x.tm_min, seconds=x.tm_sec).total_seconds()
```

Comment: He encontrado este codigo que funciona tras recibir un simple valor
x = time.strptime("00:01:00","%H:%M:%S")    -----(Siguiente linea)---


datetime.timedelta(hours=x.tm_hour,minutes=x.tm_min, seconds=x.tm_sec).total_seconds()

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto funciona.

```
df["Real time (s)"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["Real time (s)"].radd('00:')).dt.total_seconds()
print (df)

Compression_level  Size (M)  Real time (s) User time (s) Sys time (s)
0                  0       265         19.938      0:24.649      0:3.062
1                  1        76         17.910      0:25.929      0:3.098
2                  2        74         62.619      0:27.724      0:3.014
3                  3        73         20.607      0:27.937      0:3.193
4                  4        67         19.598      0:28.853      0:2.925
5                  5        67         21.032      0:30.119      0:3.206
6                  6        66         27.013      0:31.462      0:3.106
7                  7        65         27.337      0:36.226      0:3.060
8                  8        64         37.651      0:47.246      0:2.933
9                  9        64         59.241       1:8.333      0:3.027
```

Fuente:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64803005/converting-time-format-to-second-in-a-panda-dataframe#64803040]